# I need to make this page work on multiple different resolutions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I have this about page for a website I'm creating for class and my problem is whenever I resize the window at all, the picture and the text get squished together and I don't know why. I tried using percentages instead of exact pixel sizes for the borders and I have tried floating things to the left and right and I have also tried setting the position to relative instead of absolute.

```css
.p2coop{
float:left;
position: absolute;
width: 1000px;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 36px;
line-height: normal;
color: #000000;
background-color:white;
 text-align:left;
 vertical-align: left; 
 opacity: 0.6;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 880px;
  height:290px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.campaign{
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1900px;
  height: 600px;
}
.campaignblurb{
  position: relative;
  top: 1050px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1900px;
  background-color:white; 
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  padding:20px 47px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #000000;
}
.editorblurb{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 42px;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #000000;
    top: 1630px;
    width: 700px;

    right: 100px;
    background-color:white; 
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  padding:20px 47px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.editor{
  position: absolute;
  top: 1610px;
  right: 1000;
  left: 0;
  width: 880px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="p2coop">The game’s two-player cooperative mode features its own entirely
 separate campaign with a unique story, test chambers, and two new player characters ATLAS and P-body, 
 referred to as Blue and Orange by GLaDOS, a pair of bipedal Personality Construct
 based androids. This new mode forces players to reconsider everything they thought they knew about portals.
 Success will require them to not just act cooperatively, but to think cooperatively.</div>
 <img src="portal_atlas_pbody.jpg" class="right">
 <img src="portal2campaign.jpg" class="campaign">
 <div class="campaignblurb">The single-player portion of Portal 2 introduces a cast of dynamic 
 new characters, a host of fresh puzzle elements, and a much larger set of devious test chambers.
 Players will explore never-before-seen areas of the Aperture Science Labs and be reunited with GLaDOS,
 the occasionally murderous computer companion who guided them through the original game.</div>
 <div class="editorblurb">
The Puzzle Creator (also known as Puzzle Maker or Editor) is a part of the Perpetual Testing 
Initiative in Portal 2, allowing the creation of single-player
and Co-op test chambers within a simple in-game editor.
</div>
 <img src="leveleditor.jpg" class="editor">
```

Comment: Why not use standard framework like bootstrap or w3css?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this **style** with your **current style css**

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.p2coop {
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #000000;
  background-color:white;
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align: left; 
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.right {
  float:right;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height:290px;
}
.campaign {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.campaignblurb {
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
  background-color:white; 
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  padding:20px 10px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #000000;
}
.editorblurb {
  width:50%;
  float:right;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #000000;
  right: 100px;
  background-color:white; 
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  padding:20px 0px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.editor {
  width: 50%;
  height: 350px;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things you can try to make your website responsive to different screen sizes:

1) You need to write media queries to handle different resolutions as simply adding percentage won't work on all the screen sizes always. Example of using media queries in CSS is following:

Let say you have a component  which have a class 'abc' containing attribute of width 50%. But the problem is, when you will view this element in a smaller screen (e.g. mobile view) the element would be too compress and things would be messy. What you need to do is switching width to 100% based on the screen size its getting viewed on.

```
.abc{
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .abc{
      width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .abc{
      width: 70%;
    }
}
```

so here media query tells the browser to apply 50% width on an element implementing 'abc' class, but if max width of the device is 400px (e.g. might be mobile or other smaller device) then make the width 100% of same class. same as with 800px. You can implement multiple media-queries based on your business case to handle responsiveness. 
Further explanation can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) about media queries.

2) You can simply use any external responsive css library e.g. twitter's bootstrap. 
It works on 12-grid system, mean it logically divide every screen in 12 columns. It have specific css classes for different screen-sizes e.g. extra-small (xs), small (sm), medium (md) and large (lg). Following is example how you can apply these on your elements

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>
```

The above implementation would tell the browser to render this element in full 12 columns if the screen width is extra small or small, render the element in 6 columns (1/2) if screen size is medium and render the div in 4 columns (1/3) if its beings rendered on large screen.

Further documentation on how to use bootstrap to make elements responsive can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp)